# Щодо цукроварні, книгарні, ливарні

Tags: стилістика

В українській мові є чудові іменники на позначення місця виробу чи продажу певних продуктів: кав'ярня, книгарня, друкарня, цукроварня, броварня тощо.

У [статті О. І. НЕЧИТАЙЛО](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine21-26.pdf) зазначається, що поширюється тенденція заміняти ці назви на описові чи запозичені: книжковий магазин, цукровий завод, типографія. Чи використовують ще назви ливарня, гамарня, миловарня, цегельня, чи вони вважаються застарілими?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте перевіримо через словник, від якого найменше очікуємо заанґажованості у традиційно українських назвах:

1. [Цукроварня](http://sum.in.ua/s/cukrovarnja)

> Цукровий завод.

Нічого не пише про це слово як про застаріле.

2. [Книгарня](http://sum.in.ua/s/knygharnja)

> Книжкова **крамниця**.

Нічого не пише про це слово як про застаріле.

3. [Друкарня](http://sum.in.ua/s/drukarnja)

> Поліграфічне підприємство, на якому виготовляють друковану продукцію
>   різних видів.

Нічого не пише про це слово як про застаріле.

4. [Ливарня](http://sum.in.ua/s/lyvarnja)

> Майстерня, цех, де відливають металеві вироби.

Нічого не пише про це слово як про застаріле.

5. [Броварня](http://sum.in.ua/s/brovarnja)

> Пивоварний завод.

Єдине слово, про яке кажуть як про застаріле.

6. [Цегельня](http://sum.in.ua/s/cegheljnja)

> Завод, який виробляє цеглу.

Нічого не пише про це слово як про застаріле.

7. [Миловарня](http://sum.in.ua/s/mylovarnja)

> Підприємство, на якому виготовляють мило.

Он як, ні, "броварня" - не єдине, про яке пишуть як про застаріле.

Тепер ходімо перевіряти все на практиці, у новинах:

1. [Цукроварня](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%86%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKiruI6fXZAhWCaVAKHW7OCOQQ_AUIDSgE&biw=1366&bih=662) - є у новинах за 2017-18 роки. Спокійно можна вживати.
2. [Книгарня](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=nws&ei=GVauWuqJCsvewAL387nYDg&q=%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&oq=%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i19k1l2.55914.55914.0.56635.1.1.0.0.0.0.437.437.4-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.436....0.-yvCtDZrdjc) - аналоґічно.
3. [Друкарня](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=nws&ei=UlauWoe3FdGjwALrpIm4Ag&q=%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&oq=%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&gs_l=psy-ab.3...19051.19781.0.19873.8.8.0.0.0.0.122.668.1j5.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.3.344...0.0.Rg2EZaeRVs0) - те саме.
4. [Ливарня](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=nws&ei=Z1auWq_VEIKC6QSs_L7oCw&q=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&oq=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i19k1l6.17131.17739.0.17816.7.7.0.0.0.0.170.579.2j3.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.5.576...0.0.cd0nd_hGalY) - знову маємо новини з цим словом.
5. [Броварня](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=nws&ei=eVauWsKDL8yjwALaz4egAg&q=%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&oq=%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&gs_l=psy-ab.3...39852.40703.0.40802.8.7.0.1.1.0.140.570.1j4.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.5.466...0.0.pxp9CgZuIqA) - гм, зважаючи на кількість новин з цим словом за останні роки, може, не таке воно й застаріле?
6. [Цегельня](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%A6%D0%95%D0%93%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9D%D0%AF&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ_4-m7vXZAhVLY1AKHSZzDXMQ_AUIDCgD&biw=1366&bih=662) - є новини останніх років з цим слово.
7. [Миловарня](https://www.google.com.ua/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=nws&ei=b1quWseEGKSSmwWfqoHQBA&q=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&oq=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1865.5799.0.5862.15.13.2.0.0.0.134.1194.4j7.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.10.877.0..0j0i19k1.81.CQw6N-bX9pA) - маємо новини з цим словом, хоч і не так багато.

Мій особистий висновок зі всієї цієї інформації: ніякі ці слова не застарілі, а цілком собі орґанічні для нашої мови, можна ними користатися без зайвих роздумів.

Єдине слово, яке не знаходиться у значенні завода чи майстерні (де плавиться метал) - це "гамарня", воно й у СУМі значиться як застаріле. Я не зовсім впевнений у цьому, але це слово здається чи не ідентичним слову "ливарня", тож можна просто використовувати останнє.